# Custom Search Parameter for Extensions Resource on FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

Does FHIR support search based on Extension values?

I have added this extension under the ImagingStudy Resource

```
{
  "extension": [
    {
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/SearchParameter/institution-name",
      "valueString": "Apollo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to have a custom search parameter added for this extension such that it can be searched accordingly? If possible, how can I register it?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to define search parameters that look at extensions.  There's an example of one here: http://hl7.org/fhir/searchparameter-example-extension.html

However, the process of getting a given server to support those search parameters depends on what server you're using.  Some of the reference implementation servers have an ability to generically support any 'normal' SearchParameter that is appropriately registered.  Other servers will require custom coding to support new parameters.

Note that having an extension with a canonical URL that looks like a SearchParameter is going to be confusing to most implementers.  If you're using a FHIR-based canonical URL, it should be a StructureDefinition.

Comment: Went through the link you shared, it talks about registering an extension as a search parameter, but don't see any example queries made. How do I query on an Imaging Study resource to search a given extension value?

Comment: You would have to define a SearchParameter for that extension and then need to get the relevant server to support that SearchParameter.  The process for getting a server to support a new parameter varies.  Some can do it automatically.  Others will require custom development.

Comment: As a concrete example, here is the Microsoft Azure Fhir Server (or whatever marketing term they are calling it these days) link for implementing this (in THEIR world) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/how-to-do-custom-search